# Search for a PDF file in directory and send with outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am beginner in vba..

I want to create excel vba with the below criteria:

Search for PDF files with names mentioned in column A1, A2... Multiple... in a directory and if found send that file via outlook with the searched file attachment. If file not found ignore that file and move to the next file.

It should send just one file via outlook at a time then second and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub CheckandSend()
Dim obMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim irow As Integer
Dim dpath As String
Dim pfile As String

'' directory that contains files
dpath = "xxx"
'' loop through all files and send mail
irow = 1

Do While Cells(irow, 1) <> Empty
'' get file name in column A
    pfile = Dir(dpath & "\*" & Cells(irow, 1) & "*")
    '' check file exist and pdf file
    If pfile <> "" And Right(pfile, 3) = "pdf" Then
        Set obMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With obMail
            .To = "xxx@xxx.com"
            .Subject = "xxxx"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain
            .Body = "xxxx"
            .Attachments.Add (dpath & "\" & pfile)
            .Send
        End With

    End If
    '' go to next file
    pfile = pfile + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Remember to add reference Microsoft Outlook library in excel for make Mail Item.

Comment: Thank you for it. I tried the above code it is just sending the first file from the A1 column and the script is giving error "Type Mismatch". I debugged the code and its giving error at  "pfile = pfile + 1".  Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: oops , sorry, i miss type it, please use  "irow = irow + 1"